# PHP Widget layout grid

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, grid, widget

I'm building a webapp which main purpose is displaying widgets on a display. These widgets have an variable size, so not every widget is even high or wide (But they are using standards like for example a grid system). Now I'm looking for the best way to save which widgets are used, and where they are placed. For example by using something like [Gridstack](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) the user can drag and place the widgets in an admin panel, but how should I save this? And how can I recall this and put in a empty Bootstrap page for example. Working with the Bootstrap Grid system would be great aswell.

I did some research on Google and here but didn't find any plugins or ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using 'Gridster' at the moment which this Gridstack is built off of/inspired by, so it probably won't be able to save for you.

You'll need to do that, either by sending it back via AJAX or storing in local storage. As it looks similar, you should be able to find a 'serialization' function which should wrap it up ready for you to send to your PHP via AJAX.

You may need to scan through the widgets and wrap them up in your own JSON string, such as the row/column/sizex/sizey which is all the grid system really needs to "add" a widget when its first loaded up, so as long as you can feed that back in you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I might have found a litle workaround with Gridstack. What are the differences between Gridstack & Gridster? I like Gridstack its API and ways to get information about the grid, but I don't like the Size adjustment/responsiveness? Thanks

Comment: It looks like Gridstack is inspired by Gridster, so it's kind of modelled on the same idea but it does look like it packs quite a few cool features that Gridster does not. Gridster is much smaller, but more robust and a bit more mature. But it doesn't fair well on mobile devices either! Gridster has a serialize function, that allows you to wrap it up ready for you to fire off to PHP (if you want to save it to a db) then on page load I build up the table in PHP based off the saved settings.